# Kafka configuration not loaded from Spring config server in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have microservice projects access to a common config server. However the configuration for the Eugene client is working, but for the apache Kafka not working.

Spring Config server

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableConfigServer
public class FeteBirdConfigurationServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FeteBirdConfigurationServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/anandjaisy/Microservice-Cloud-Config
```

**Config server**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: CONFIG-SERVER
server:
  port: 8085
```

**Git Repo**

```
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

Micoservice accessing config server

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri:
        - http://localhost:8085
```

If I put Kafka config in the microservice application.yml file the configuration works, but if I remove and try to access the config server it is not working.
spring:
application:
name: ORDER-SERVICE
kafka:
producer:
value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

Logs from the microservice

```
2020-07-13 15:11:08.441  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8085
2020-07-13 15:11:08.992  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8085. Will be trying the next url if available
2020-07-13 15:11:08.999  WARN 2025 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8085/ORDER-SERVICE/dev": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2020-07-13 15:11:09.004  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] f.b.f.FeteBirdOrderApplication           : The following profiles are active: dev
2020-07-13 15:11:17.529  WARN 2025 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2020-07-13 15:11:18.328  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=0bb24ffe-2fc1-3960-867f-4b6e7735d255
2020-07-13 15:11:20.952  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2020-07-13 15:11:21.095  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-07-13 15:11:21.096  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
2020-07-13 15:11:21.612  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-07-13 15:11:21.613  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 12525 ms
2020-07-13 15:11:22.495  WARN 2025 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2020-07-13 15:11:22.495  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2020-07-13 15:11:22.541  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@59982a7
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/Users/macbook/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.2.7.RELEASE/56e14a3a5e2813534b5db2da1502cd58ab5bc61d/spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-07-13 15:11:31.448  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 17 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-07-13 15:11:32.508  WARN 2025 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2020-07-13 15:11:32.508  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2020-07-13 15:11:32.931  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-07-13 15:11:33.094  WARN 2025 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : Unable to start LiveReload server
2020-07-13 15:11:34.161  WARN 2025 --- [  restartedMain] ockingLoadBalancerClientRibbonWarnLogger : You already have RibbonLoadBalancerClient on your classpath. It will be used by default. As Spring Cloud Ribbon is in maintenance mode. We recommend switching to BlockingLoadBalancerClient instead. In order to use it, set the value of `spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled` to `false` or remove spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon from your project.
```

Comment: share the logs of the microservice printing the config client bootstrap logs and double check whether it has picked your properties/yaml file from git repo.

Comment: @Barath I am running the multiple projects in the IDE. But for the Eureka config it is working

Comment: Logs are very clear that it couldnt communicate wtih config server ```2020-07-13 15:11:08.999  WARN 2025 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8085/ORDER-SERVICE/dev": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2020-07-13 15:11:09.004  INFO 2025 --- [  restartedMain] f.b.f.FeteBirdOrderApplication           : The following profiles are active: dev```.

Comment: With the config, you are connecting to config server directly not through discovery client. And double check the name of the service registered in git repo and finally make sure the config server is started and port is correct. you can simply do a curl to check ```curl http://localhost:8085/ORDER-SERVICE/dev``` to check whether it is working or not.

Comment: http://localhost:8085/ORDER-SERVICE/dev is working for me, that logs is printed at the beginning because I am running multiple projects on the IDE, the microservice might be running first before the config server, may be that's the reason the logs are working, however the eureka config is working fine for me.

Comment: Well if config server is itself a eureka client then you could opt to use discovery client to discover your config server rather than url. You could also confirm by starting the config server first and then the Microservice to narrow down the issue

Comment: Docs: [discovery client](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html)

Comment: Yes, the config server is a Discovery client. It is register in Eureka

Comment: Try changing the config as per the doc using bootstrap discovery and see it works. It should work though.

Comment: I was trying to implement Discovery first approach, but not able to implement. Can you please provide one example